# validate datetime input uniqueness in CreateView form

Tags: python, django

I have this model, and what I need is the time to be unique as it's a Reservation, so when I create a new reservation, how can I check if that time is already picked.

**models.py**

```
class Reserva(models.Model):
    horario = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=False)
    cancha = models.ForeignKey('Cancha', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    lote = models.IntegerField()
```

**views.py**

```
class ReservasCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    template_name = 'reservar.html'
    fields = ['horario', 'cancha', 'lote']
```

**reservation.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Reservar">
</form>
```

And another doubt I have, if I want to change some input types in the form, should I keep the default CreateView and modify it over the view, or create a custom form in forms.py and pass it as form_class. What's the recomendation? Thanks

Comment: Do you have a `form` from where you get the data ? or you get them elsewhere ?

Comment: I get the date through the CreateView default form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the creation of reservations's date to be `unique` in the database level by adding:

```
horario = models.DateTimeField(unique=True)
```

Or, you can override the `form_valid()` method in order to check if the date is picked or not and rise an exception or whatever you want:

```
from django.contrib import messages # better than raising an exception
from app_name import models # import your APP models 

class ReservasCreateView(generic.edit.CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    template_name = 'reservar.html'
    fields = ['horario', 'cancha', 'lote']
    success_url = 'YOUR_SUCCESS_URL'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        date = form.cleaned_data.get('horario', None)
        # check if the date is unique
        # If we find the same date stored in the database
        # we'll add a message to be rendered into the template
        dates = models.Reserva.objects.filter(horario=date).first()
        if dates:
            messages.error(self.request, "This current date is not unique!")
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

And then in your template you can add the messages framework like this example:

```
{% for message in messages %}
    {{ message }}
{% endfor %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Reservar">
</form>
```

For more information you can visit the [django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user)

Comment: Thanks, I haven't seen the second way, do you have the documentation?

Comment: Thank you, that's better, but with the last edit, it's not showing the message and saving the reservation

Comment: You need to edit your template too. See the template section i've added in my answer.

Comment: I edited both view and template. I put some code inside the if statement and it works, should I return something inside the if?

Comment: no, just use the `message` framework builtin with django. And all you have to do is to render it inside your template.  See here [Simple better than complex](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/09/06/django-tip-14-messages-framework.html)

Comment: Welcome and happy coding :D